# AWS Textract Parser

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-textract

Is the download results button available through cli for the AWS Textract? or is the parser that AWS uses is available online? Already tried searching for it but with no luck.

Comment: You can use its APIs to get the extracted JSON. I am not sure about the CLI. I am developing its parser on my own. I don't think there is any parser available for it.

Answer (score 0):

The CLI for textract is available [here](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/textract/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

Textract has provided example code such as parsing response for key-value pairs - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/textract/latest/dg/examples-extract-kvp.html.

Exporting tables into CSV - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/textract/latest/dg/examples-export-table-csv.html

There is general parser available on github as well: https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-textract-response-parser

Visit this page for more detail on example code for parsers: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/textract/latest/dg/other-examples.html